# PrimeNG: MenuItem icon from asset folder not showing

Tags: angular, primeng

I added icon from asset folder for PrimeNG MenuItem like this following, but it is not showing.

```
    this.menu = [
        {
            label: 'Dashboard',
            icon: 'dashboard-icon'
        }
    ]
```

In css,

```
.dashboard-icon { background-image: url("./assets/icons/dashboard.svg"); }
```

Am I missing something, or what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

The icon class is set deep within the angular component. therefore, to set your own class, you must use `ng-deep`. So this should solve your issue:

```
:host ::ng-deep .dashboard-icon { background-image: url("./assets/icons/dashboard.svg"); }
```

Comment: still not showing the icon, do you think I missed any prefix on this line?
icon: 'dashboard-icon'

Comment: can you see your icon if you just show it in an `<i>` or a `span`?

You may also need to add a class/ styling to set height etc